Distribution of a product of random variables
I have two independent distributions $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is defined by the piecewise CDF
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
F_X^1(x) & x \in (-\infty, a_1)\\
F_X^2(x) & x \in [a_1, a_2)\\
F_X^3(x) & x \in [a_2, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
and PDF
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
f_X^1(x) & x \in (-\infty, a_1)\\
f_X^2(x) & x \in [a_1, a_2)\\
f_X^3(x) & x \in [a_2, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
and Y is defined by the piecewise CDF
$$F_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}
F_Y^1(y) & y<0\\
F_Y^2(y) & y\geq0
\end{cases}$$
and PDF
$$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}
f_Y^1(y) & y<0\\
f_Y^2(y) & y\geq0
\end{cases}$$
What is the CDF and PDF of $Z = Xe^Y$?

I've tried to break the problem down using the Law of Total Probability (I omitted some terms below), but I get stuck at the last step. I don't know how to convert this to an integral with the right bounds.
\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(Z<z)    &=\mathbb{P}(Xe^{Y}<z) \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y}) \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},ze^{-Y} < a_{1})+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},a_{1} \leq ze^{-Y} < a_{2})+\dots\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y) \\
    &\qquad+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{2}\right) < Y \leq \ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right))+\dots \\
    &=\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y,Y<0) \\
    &\qquad+\mathbb{P}(X<ze^{-Y},\ln(z)-\ln\left(a_{1}\right) \leq Y,Y\geq0)+\dots \end{align*}

I'm not sure if this is a good answer, but perhaps you should look into the Mellin transform.

In your question $X$ and $Y$ would be random variables, not distributions (the Fs are their distributions).

Does $F_X^2(x)$ mean the square of the function $F_X(x)$, that is, $F_X^2(x) = [F_X(x)]^2$ or are there three different functions (expressions) (which might better be denoted as $F_X^{(i)}(x),  i=1,2,3$ which emphasizes that the superscript is not a power)?_  Also, do you need to impose conditions to ensure that $F_X(x)$ is continuous (and nondecreasing) at $a_1$ and  $a_2$?

One generally effective way to work algebraically with functions defined piecewise is to express them as linear combinations of indicators.  E.g., $F_y(y)=\mathcal I(y\lt 0) F_Y^1 + \mathcal I(y\ge 0)F_Y^2.$ That reduces your question to one of very basic algebraic manipulation (which, admittedly, will produce a linear combination of $3\times 2=6$ terms, but that's no conceptual hurdle).
